# Boostrap draw two panels on one column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My objective is basically this:

```
+-----------------------------+
|      A      ||      B       |
+-----------------------------+
|             ||              |
|             ||              |
|             ||      Btext   |
|             ||              |
|     Atext   ||              |
|             ||              |
|             |---------------|
|             |               |
|             |               |
|             |               |
|             |               |
|             |     Ctext     |
|             |               |
|             |               |
|             |               |
+-------------+---------------+
```

I have the following snippet:

```
<div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;margin:0px;">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3><span id="headerLeftPlanel">A</span>&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i></h3>
        <hr />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h3>B</h3>
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;margin:0px;">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="max-height: 92vh;overflow-y: scroll;">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
        <div class="row" style="min-height:40%">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
                BText
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
               Ctext
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, my BText and CText do not ajust to the page's height.
What layout should I use instead?
I have tried to set `min-height` to BText but it didn't work, the two rows get shrinked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They do not adjust, because you have not defined a height, neither in the left, nor in the right container. What you defined is a `max-height: 92vh` in the left container and a `min-height: 40%` on the right container, setting the right one to minimum `40%` of left container's height. This results in your described problem:

[image]

You can solve this by either:

1. Defining a height on the left container like `height: 92vh`. See [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/34w6e2q8/9/)
2. Defining a height on the right container like `min-height: 40vh`. See [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/34w6e2q8/12/)

The result is the following:

[image: Result]